# While running a script as testng in eclipse using appium. It tells me a new session could not be created

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium, web-inspector

While running a script as testng in eclipse using appium. It tells me a new session could not be created.

The error is as below:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
>       org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected
>   Android device.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 27.86 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
>       System info: host: 'Emnas-Mac.local', ip: '192.168.116.130', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>       Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:161)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:170)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:82)
>         at test.HomePage.setUp(HomePage.java:30)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
>
> Here is my setup method:
>
> ```
> AndroidDriver driver;
>
>
> //UiDevice mydevice = getUiDevice();
> @BeforeClass
> public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
>     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
>     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "6b1cffac");
>     capabilities.setCapability("version", "5.0.1");
>     capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
>     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "MyPackage"); 
>     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.gtl.activity.SplashActivity");
>     driver =   new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
>     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}
> ```
>
> I also get this exception : [TestNG] Running:
>   /private/var/folders/b4/4xhr5zcs3y75f17swbzvkbj40000gn/T/testng-eclipse-661364855/testng-customsuite.xml
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.48.2',
>   revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52' System info: host:
>   'Emnas-Mac.local', ip: '192.168.116.130', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
>   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:161) at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:170) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:82) at
>   test.HomePage.setUp(HomePage.java:30) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773) at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018) at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111) at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204) at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
>   System info: host: 'Emnas-Mac.local', ip: '192.168.116.130', os.name:
>   'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_65' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:79)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)

My problem is that the code runs fine if i close appium and restart it again and clean up, build my project in eclipse. So else if i run it again a got an exception. Am i obliged to restart appium and clean up my project each time i want to run my script?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: "Could not find a connected Android device." is your biggest clue. Either the AVD you wanted it to start didn't start, or your connected device couldn't be found. If it's AVD, re-check your ANDROID_HOME path, and/or start it up manually. If it's a connected device, make sure the developer tools are turned on and USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: run appium-doctor to check all environment variables are set properly, one more thing before starting test check "adb devices" ensure device connected.

Comment: share you code please

Comment: I have posted my setup method, but my problem is that the code runs fine if i close appium and restart it again and clean up, build my project in eclipse. So else if i run it again a got an exception. Am i obliged to restart appium and clean up my project each time i want to run my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emna You can reduce the timeout using appium server capability

```
capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout","30");
```

Refer : http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities

> **--command-timeout   60  The default command timeout for the server to use for all sessions. Will still be overridden by newCommandTimeout cap**

Comment: This error appears to me some times not all the time. I didn't know the reson. some time i refresh+build the project and restart appium in order to avoid it

Comment: @Emna .your right..this occurs majorly when u re run the script immediately after makin some code changes. Set this to 10 secs and observe the device would close down the session. After which u run the suite a new session will create and this error won't occur

Comment: Ok. Thank you @karhick